# Graphic Design Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :D

Comment: After voting/commenting on all of them, I think they are all quite valuable to the site. Specially because we don't have as many visitors as other SE yet. Some are more interesting than others, and some are more "valuable", but I definitely don't think forbidding questions are going to do any good. In any case, I'd go for asking more questions ourselves, and creating good answers for them.

Comment: I agree with Yisela. Our problem is not the questions. It's the lack of questions, which comes from the lower-than-desirable number of practising designers using the site. That comes from the low number of questions (less reason for people to come back), its low profile (few routes for people to find the site) and an atmosphere that often seems unfriendly and unwelcoming (discouraging people to get involved). See our site stats http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design and our users' steep rep curve http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter

Comment: why do you think it's unfriendly and unwelcoming? I mean, when I joined I felt a little overwhelmed by how much everyone knows their stuff, but nobody was ever rude to me. Do you have examples?

Comment: @yisela I don't mean people actually being rude, and often we're fine, but I often see new people's questions being closed with little or no feedback or explanation - and unsurprisingly, those people don't come back

Comment: @user568458 Can you provide links to questions that have been closed without any feedback or explanation?

Comment: Completely offtopic, but everytime I read "Let's Get Critical!" my mind sings it in the tone of Madonna's "Let's get physical (physicaaaal...)"

Comment: @yisela That's actually Olivia Newton-John. :P

Comment: @Aarthi oh my, you are right, must be the diabolic Glee influence!!

Comment: @yisela *shakes fist* Glee!

Comment: @yisela Also, the entire team starts humming that song any time we look at these evals, hahaha.

Comment: **Thanks for your help, everyone!**

Answer (score 3):

[Finding the "base" color of a gradient . . .?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7285/finding-the-base-color-of-a-gradient)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: More on the Graphic Theory side, perhaps not as seo friendly but definitely interesting. I believe these are the kind of questions that give people curiosity about the site

Comment: I really like this question, I wish it had got some more answers.

Comment: +1 excellent...

Answer (score 3):

[Looking for a font similar to Georgia, but without the numbers dipping as they do](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/a-font-similar-to-georgia-but-without-the-numbers-dipping-as-they-do)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Quite specific but a font related question that is not identification is always welcomed :)

Comment: +1 good one, enough specific to attract specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

[Feedback on Basic Website Logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/feedback-on-basic-website-logo)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I am divided about these questions. I asked something around this in meta, but more in relation to "how to represent". Feedback is one thing, Willow's answer was really good (maybe too good, she worked hard!). In any case, this question was vague and lacked real value.

Comment: I like these questions. I understand the case against, but we do offer something genuinely different to sites like Dribbble which often seem like a wall of shallow compliments. We offer a more analytical community and a better structure for problem solving. There's a fine line between seeking critique as problem solving and just generally sticking things up, but I think people understand where that line is and this is a good example that shows it can work and that we offer something extra.

Comment: After reading your comment and http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/244/who-are-we-talking-to-and-what-are-we-offering I think I understand how these questions can improve the site. So... maybe they are valuable.

Comment: +1 this is the best so far, I would like to have more creative questions :D

Answer (score 2):

[Tools for making infographics](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7216/tools-for-making-infographics)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question with valuable answers, grabs people's attention too

Comment: -1 too narrow, time wasting to read.

Comment: @hhh I don't understand why you've downvoted every question that doesn't directly relate to your work? I see you're primarily a StackOverflow user, so you already understand that on SO questions can be very specific and that it's normal for people to only read questions about topics they are interested in. It's the same here. There's no expectation that every question should be relevant to every designer, because every designer's work is different.

Comment: @user568458 cut, I did not understand a word of your writing sorry.

Answer (score 2):

[Dither and Gradients](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7277/dither-and-gradients)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Excellent for educational purposes, someone asking something like this is more likely to stay (and learn more, probably)

Comment: Solid question, solid answer. This is the sort of thing the site is great for - clear answers and people sharing and adding titbits of specific knowledge and experience so everyone is learning something.

Comment: ...too localized, -1. Time-wasting after clicking to find it is only about a very specific software niche, it would be useful to narrow such questions already in title or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

[Which are the most prominent creative thinking techniques/methodologies?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7215/which-are-the-most-prominent-creative-thinking-techniques-methodologies)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: For me, in the same tone of "Finding a base color...", quite interesting

Comment: +1 Good stuff, something to learn.

Answer (score 1):

[Is there a DIN font free alternative?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7178/din-font-free-alternative)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: "freebie scavengers", usually do more searches than reading :P

Comment: I don't like font questions personally, but I think they're important for the site. Plenty of people like them and they give people an easy way to interact with the site. Our biggest problem is getting designers to find out our site exists and having enough new material to interact with to  keep them coming back, and font questions seem to work well for that.

Comment: +1 good one, exact enough to attract variety of answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Create icons from sprite image](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7274/create-icons-from-sprite-image)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I like these general questions, they attract people and have a little more content to them, as they usually turn into tutorials and therefore, quality answers

Comment: This shows that a question doesn't have to be brilliantly worded to get a solid, useful answer. (shame the guy didn't also share the script he mentioned...)

Comment: -1 this is not general question because it is only about photoshop, I was going to answer how to do it with one-liner but then noticed the small label "photoshop" so stopped answering. It is misleading that there is a label photoshop and then the guy mentions some *ix tool. I wish the labels such as Photoshop/Gimp/Inkscape/Adobe/branding were banned, you could use search instead -- too confusing. Otherwise I like this question, now it is too narrow...there are better ways to do this thing :P

Comment: @hhh I think he added photoshop because it was one of his possibilities (wonder he didn't tag it as Gimp too!), but answers using other technologies are always welcomed. You can still answer it, it might be of great help for someone else. Rather than answering a person, you would be adding content to the site/subject.

Comment: I would remove my downvote if *ix -style answer are really allowed :D ...hopefully helping someone :)

Answer (score 1):

[Gimp: Save tiff with a "Group 4 Fax" compression](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7208/gimp-save-tiff-with-a-group-4-fax-compression)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: I think the technical questions can be good for very specific searches, but I doubt how many of the people asking them stay around and turn into active participants

Comment: I agree with yisela: there will always be questions like this, they're not exciting, but having a good back catalogue of really specific questions like this means there's a way for designers googling similarly specific problems to discover our site. They're unglamourous but important.

Comment: ...again worried that too localized...

Comment: @hhh I don't understand what you think this site is for? A designer had a design related problem, asked a question about it, and got a useful answer. If another designer googles a similar problem, they might find this answer useful and might discover this site. This question isn't exiting, but you'd never normally have read it unless you had the same problem - in which case, you would find it useful. This isn't a magazine or a tutorial site. It's for people looking for answers to specific problems. This isn't a great question (hence no upvotes) but there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @huh if you are looking for a design magazine with tutorials where an editor makes sure all the content is engaging to a particular subset of designers, these exist. I'm guessing Smashing Magazine might suit you, for example. But we're not trying to be one of those. We're trying to be a place where people can get, give, and share expert answers to specific problems.

Comment: @hhh It is indeed very localised, but I think it's still good to have some of these "catalogue" questions. Specially because they will only appear in the Home once, and then they will wait in Limbo until someone searches for them :)

Answer (score 0):

[amalgamation morphing effects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7202/amalgamation-morphing-effects)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This question in particular is quite vague and doesn't show too much research

Comment: It's a lazily written question, but it still resulted in interesting content. Room for improvement, but no harm done.